# Render only One Row in link_to_add_association using cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, polymorphic-associations, cocoon-gem

I have `HomeBannerSlider` model which has  `has_many` relation wih `Image`.
I used the `cocoon gem` to add multiple association

to render images i used following code in y form

```
 = f.simple_fields_for :images do |image|
            = render 'image_fields', f: image
          .links
            = link_to_add_association 'Add Image', f, :images
```

in image field i used the following code

```
div.col-lg-12.nested-fields
  div.sub_box.col-lg-12
   .form-group.col-md-3
     = f.input :title, input_html: {class: "form-control"}
     .form-group.col-md-3
     = f.input :description, input_html: {class: "form-control"}
     .form-group.col-md-3
      = f.input :image, as: :file, input_html: {class: "form-control"}
   .form-group.col-md-3
      = image_tag f.object.image.url(:thumb) if                    f.object.image.present?
  = link_to_remove_association "remove image", f
```

My problem is that whenever i click on `link_to_add_association` it build and renders **three** new records of images. But i want it to render only one record on each click.

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: The code looks good, so this is is most likely a turbolinks problem. Make sure you include `cocoon.js` inside your application.js, and include your `application.js` in the `<head>` of your application layout.

Comment: Thanks @nathanvda  for response, i figured it out. it was js issue.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/177

For anyone having this issue. It is due to the application.js or cocoon.js being called multiple times.

Edit:
The issue was in the 'view' folder in a rails application. 
the 'application.html.erb' file i called the line "javascript_include_tag 'application' " twice, so it ran the add row code twice so i end up with 2 or more rows. Make sure you only have 1 of those and that should fix it.

Comment: please post the gist of the solution here, the issue or github repository might get deleted and won't be useful for future users.

Comment: Please provide explanation along with link as it may not work in future